# Powershell can't save xml output to variable, file

Tags: xml, powershell

For some reason I can't redirect xml output of a program to the file or anywhere. The command is:

```
node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript

<testsuite name="Mocha Tests" tests="40" failures="0" errors="0" skipped="0" timestamp="Wed, 16 Oct 2013 11:03:28 GMT" t
ime="0.664">
<testcase classname="Testing preview" name="preview index is set to correct value" time="0.007"/>
...
```

However, when I want to save that to a file, nothing works. Only first line is saved. I tried the following:

```
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript >result.xml
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript | tee result.xml
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript | out-file result.xml
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript | out-string result.xml
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript | set-content result.xml
 node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript | add-content result.xml
 iex(node ...) | out-string results.xml
 $res = node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript
```

In each of above cases only first line is saved.

Comment: Are you sure you're not seeing the whole XML document on a single line?

Comment: It doesn't look like that. And in that case, saving to variable would do the trick. Also `out-file -width 10000` doesn't do anything. In plain old cmd.exe it works as expected (with new lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found is this:

```
cmd /c "node "$mocha" --reporter xunit "$testScript" > result.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a WAG, since I don't have that executable, but:

```
(node $mocha --reporter xunit $testScript) |  add-content result.xml
```

Comment: Nope. Added this one as another fail. It saves only last line. I am starting to think that this is a bug. If variable doesn't receive the text, I guess all redirection options are doomed.

Comment: Not necessarily.  Updated the script (replaced set-content with add-content).  Let's see what that does.

Comment: No. What do you mean not necessarily ? If I can't save it into var how can I save it elsewhere...

Comment: In your inial post you indicated only the first line was saved.  When the output was piped to set-content, you say only the last line was saved.  This seems to indicate that the first solution is ending the re-direction too soon, and the set-content is working but overwriting the previous content, so add-content should capture all of the lines.

Comment: Never mentioned last line. Only first line is ever shown in anything that grabs the text.

Comment: Your first comment starts out: "Nope. Added this one as another fail. It saves only last line."